# Error executing Ant sql task with Sybase

Tags: sql, ant, sybase

I have written a buildfile which at certain points installs objects in a Sybase database.

The code is provided by our developers, and I'm not allowed to modify it.
If run the given SQL manually using the `isql` command, it works.

This is the part of the buildfile that installs a given object:

```
<sql
    driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.user}"
    password="${db.password}" src="${file}"
    print="true" delimiter="go" delimitertype="row"
    classpathref="sybase.lib.path" output="${file}.out"
    errorproperty="install.failed" onerror="continue" keepformat="true" />
```

Although the solution works most of the time, every time that I try to run a script that contains a double quote (") it fails.

For example if the SQL script contains something like this:

```
declare @var varchar(30)
set @var = "SOME STRINGS"
```

it fails with the error:

```
[sql] com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Invalid column name 'SOME STRINGS'.
```

Did someone solve this issue?

I've read the documentation for the [Ant `sql` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html).
I'm using Ant version 1.8.2.

I have tested with the following jdbc drivers:

- com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
- net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Comment: You could try to set escapeprocessing to false

Comment: @Matteo i've tried that and i get the same error.

Comment: Finally i replaced the use of SQL task tag for the following sentences:
<exec executable="isql">
      <arg value="-S${isql.server}"/>
      <arg value="-U${db.user}"/>
      <arg value="-P${db.password}"/>
      <arg value="-D${isql.database}"/>
      <arg value="-o${file}.out"/>
      <arg value="-i${file}"/>
    </exec>
<own:validateISQLResult outPutProperty="install.failed" logFile="${file}.out" failOnError="false" />

Comment: I'd be interested to know whether the answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

When the session is established it has the setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set to true by default.  I believe you can adjust this with a server setting, but in any case, you can set if for the session by appending this to the url:

```
?SQLINITSTRING=set quoted_identifier off
```

so the url might look like look like:

```
"jdbc:sybase:Tds:<server>:<port>/<db>?SQLINITSTRING=set quoted_identifier off"
```

If you have multiple settings join them with ampersands `&`. See [also](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X64136.htm):

> **quoted_identifier**
>
> determines whether Adaptive Server recognizes
>   delimited identifiers within double quotation marks. By default,
>   quoted_identifier is off and all identifiers must either:
>
> - Conform to the rules for valid identifiers.
> - Be enclosed in brackets.
>
> If you use set quoted_identifier on, double quotation marks behave the
>   way brackets do, and you can use table, view, and column names that
>   begin with a nonalphabetic character, including characters that would
>   not otherwise be allowed, or are reserved words, by enclosing the
>   identifiers within double quotation marks. Delimited identifiers
>   cannot exceed 28 bytes, may not be recognized by all front-end
>   products, and may produce unexpected results when used as parameters
>   to system procedures.
>
> When quoted_identifier is on, all character strings enclosed within
>   double quotes are treated as identifiers. Use single quotes around
>   character or binary strings.